# need help rotating an object about the z-axis using animation

Tags: plotting, animation, rotation

This should be an easy question for anyone familiar with 3D animations. I have a 2D shape denoted by the equation

$$((x-1)^2+y^2) ((x+1)^2+y^2)=1$$

and I want to illustrate its relation to a [horn torus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HornTorus.html). To do this, I would like to rotate it about the $z$-axis in 3-space and have an outline of the shape be created behind it.  I appreciate any help you guys can give me.

Comment: Check out [SphericalPlot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SphericalPlot3D.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, then the short answer is

```
SphericalPlot3D[Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[Cos[2*(φ + Pi/2)]], {φ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 3/2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here a longer explanation on how to achieve this. Be warned that there is surely an easier method.

First of all, you have an equation in $x$ and $y$ which cannot simply be converted into a closed-form function $f(x)$. Nevertheless, you can plot it using [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContourPlot.html) which searches for the points that fulfill your equation.

```
ContourPlot[((x - 1)^2 + y^2) ((x + 1)^2 + y^2) == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here, you notice that the plot is kind of *radial to the origin*, and I had the feeling that your equation might be simpler in polar coordinates.

```
expr = TransformedField["Cartesian" -> "Polar", 
  ((x - 1)^2 + y^2) ((x + 1)^2 + y^2) - 1, {x, y} -> {r, phi}] // FullSimplify
(* r^4 - 2 r^2 Cos[2 phi] *)
```

Indeed, this looks way better. We can solve this for `r` and get

```
expr2 = r /. Solve[expr == 0, r] // Last
(* Sqrt[2] Sqrt[Cos[2 phi]] *)
```

an explicit function $r(phi)$ which can be plotted in polar coordinates

```
PolarPlot[expr2, {phi, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The only thing left is to rotate this plot about 90 degrees by adding `Pi/2` to `phi` so that [`SphericalPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SphericalPlot3D.html) creates the surface in the right form.

Answer (score 2):

You are fortunate here that your implicit equation was easily converted to a simple form in spherical coordinates, as in halirutan's solution. Had the equation not readily allowed such a conversion, you can proceed in the following way.

Starting from your implicit 2D equation, and assuming that it is the $x$-$z$ cross-section of your desired surface of revolution, we can obtain the implicit equation of the surface through the substitutions $x\mapsto\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $y\mapsto z$:

```
eq = ((x - 1)^2 + y^2) ((x + 1)^2 + y^2) == 1 /. {x -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], y -> z}
   ((-1 + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^2 + z^2) ((1 + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^2 + z^2) == 1
```

To "rationalize" the equation, one can use `GroebnerBasis[]`:

```
eq = GroebnerBasis[eq, {x, y}] // First // FullSimplify
   x^4 - 2 (y - z) (y + z) + 2 x^2 (-1 + y^2 + z^2) + (y^2 + z^2)^2
```

The result can now be fed into `ContourPlot3D[]`:

```
ContourPlot3D[x^4 - 2 (y - z) (y + z) + 2 x^2 (-1 + y^2 + z^2) + (y^2 + z^2)^2 == 0,
              {x, -Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]}, {y, -Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]}, {z, -1, 1}, 
              ContourStyle -> FaceForm[Red, Opacity[1/2, Blue]]]
```

[image: lemniscatoid of revolution]

Finally, here's a way to check that the spherical equation derived by halirutan is the same as the implicit Cartesian equation derived in this answer:

```
FullSimplify[eq /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> Sqrt[2] Sqrt[Cos[2 (φ + π/2)]]
                          {Cos[θ] Sin[φ], Sin[θ] Sin[φ], Cos[φ]}]]
   0
```